# Issue with copying data from webpage to clipboard

Tags: vba

I have referenced MS Internet Controls and MS HTML Object Library. But my copy and and past functionality of a webpage does not have anything on the clipboard. This is my piece of code

```
ieApp.navigate "https://www.tm3.com/mmdrewrite/mmd/14902.faces"
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop


Worksheets(1).Activate
Range("A1").Select
ieApp.ExecWB OLECMDID_SELECTALL, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER
ieApp.ExecWB OLECMDID_COPY, OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT

Range("A1").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

This code does not paste anything. Any help would be great

Comment: Works for me using a different URL (your link is behind a login page)

Comment: Yes it is behind a login page. I tried with a different webpage but it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Add DoEvents and Sleeps, e.g.,

```
IE2.ExecWB OLECMDID_SELECTALL, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER
DoEvents
Sleep 500
IE2.ExecWB OLECMDID_COPY, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER
DoEvents
Sleep 1000
```